# Correct exception type for adding to an array when it isn't allowed?

Tags: php, arrays, exception

Let's say I have a class that implements `ArrayAccess` but doesn't allow the addition of new data.  You can set already existing values, but you can't add to the size.

```
$arrayAccessible[1] = new StdClass(); //okay
$arrayAccessible[] = new StdClass(); //should throw an exception
```

What exception type should I throw?  I do have SPL exception types available and should use them if it makes sense.  The best I can think of is perhaps `BadFunctionCallException` or `BadMethodCallException`.

If there isn't a good one to throw, perhaps I'll make `UnsupportedOperationException` or the like.  However, that is definitely not something I'd like to do.  That would be incredibly hard to add in this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I would throw an [OverflowException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.overflowexception.php).  Since the array is fixed, it is by definition full as well...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say `UnsupportedOperationException` is good enough - it describes the problem that occurred well and fellow developer should be able to figure out what happened easily. If you aren't sure or want to be more specific, create your own exception.

Also, I wouldn't probably use `ArrayAccess` (unless you are working with legacy code) if I wanted to have fields read only. Getters should do the trick. If you want to iterate over object's properties, implement also [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface.

Comment: You misunderstood: you can modifiy it, you just cannot increase the size of the array.   Also, creating a new exception is my last option to take.  I'd MUCH rather throw an existing one.  I don't think you quite understand how much, but it's a big deal to make a new one.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. `UnsupportedOperationException` still sounds good to me - just perhaps specify what went wrong in its message. Just as a backup to my statement, check comment from `baldurien at bbnwn dot` on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php. He uses the same exception in similar situation to yours.

Comment: Note that he's quoting a Java exception, not a PHP one.  Java is where I got the name `UnsupportedOperationException` from.  It does not exist in PHP, and baldurien did NOT throw it in PHP.

Comment: Ah crap, I should learn to read. I'm not familiar with SPL exceptions and missed that "make" in your question. Anyway, I'd use `LogicException` for sure: `Exception that represents error in the program logic. This kind of exceptions should directly lead to a fix in your code.` `BadFunctionCallException` wouldn't be a good choice as it is `Exception thrown if a callback refers to an undefined function or if some arguments are missing.` which isn't correct in your case.